# Chat plug-in with document share for ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Does anyone know any chat plug-in which will support a simple chat application like WhatsApp Web kind of thing with document share support? Means user can send a document to another user like WhatsApp web.

I know using Signal-R, we can this kind of chat application but not sure along with document share support.

Comment: I don’t know if the document user shared is viewed online or downloaded. If download, you can add two action (upload, download), when user sharing docuemnt, can upload the document from client to server, then give a link. Then someone view it, can download it through the link.

Comment: Yes, link sharing is one of the option but I wanted to implement something like direct file share using drag & drop OR select file through file upload control.